# I'm having an error with styled-components that I don't understand

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to use variables in the `useContext` of `ThemeContext` in a React project, but I'm getting an error that says "The 'colors' property does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme | undefined'.".

I have already created a `style.d.ts` definition file that contains this data, but I'm still getting the same error. My class in `.tsx` is as follows:

```
import Switch from "react-switch";
import { Container, Icon } from "./Switcher.Style";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "styled-components";

interface IProps {
  toggleTheme(): void;
}

const Switcher: React.FC<IProps> = ({ toggleTheme }) => {
  const { colors, title } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const MoonIcon = () => {
    return <Icon></Icon>;
  };

  const SunIcon = () => {
    return <Icon>☀️</Icon>;
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Switch
        onChange={toggleTheme}
        checked={title === "light"}
        height={20}
        width={40}
        checkedIcon={false}
        uncheckedIcon={false}
        handleDiameter={20}
        offColor={colors.secondary}
        onColor={colors.primary}
        uncheckedHandleIcon={<MoonIcon />}
        checkedHandleIcon={<SunIcon />}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Switcher;
```